# In a work item in Azure DevOps, how can I change the target date's default time to be 11:59pm instead of 12:00am?

Tags: azure-devops

Right now if I choose a target date for a work item (e.g. Feb 3), the time is set as 12:00am by default, meaning that the actual due date, as I typically use that term, is a day before (Feb 2).

Is there a way to change the default time setting so that when I enter the due date, it will come up as {due date} 11:59PM instead of me having to set the due date to {due date + 1}?

I tried to look in user settings for an option, but couldn't find one.

Comment: I too have same doubt. Can't we change the default timing comes in the work item?

Answer (score 1):

[image]
[image]

If you don't set any initial value, then it will show as blank in the work item.

[image]
[image]

If you set the option to current date and time, then it shows the current date-time as default.

[image]

If you set the Due Date option to the some date value, then it shows the time as `12:00 AM`.

These are the only options available I believe in the `Azure DevOps > Organization Settings > Process` and tried adding the [Custom Field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/custom-controls-process?view=azure-devops) but didn't get the desired result as custom time field.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, setting the default time for Date/Time type fields on the UI is not supported.

As a workaround, you can run the following PowerShell scripts to set a default time for a Date/Time type field using REST API. **Please note, this only works for the inherited process.**

```
$token = "{PAT}"
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
$url="https://dev.azure.com/{Org name}/_apis/work/processes/{Process ID}/workItemTypes/{Work item type}/fields?api-version=5.0"
$body = @'
{
    "defaultValue": "2024-01-29T21:59:00.000Z",
    "referenceName": "Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.TargetDate",
    "readOnly": false,
    "required": false,
    "allowGroups": null,
    "allowedValues": null
}
'@
$head = @{ Authorization =" Basic $token" }
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -Headers $head -Body $body -ContentType application/json
```

- PAT: A Personal Access Token created by a PCA. Since only the PCA has permissions to change the process.
- Org name: Your organization name.
- Process ID: The process ID of your target process. You can run this REST API [Processes - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/processes/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) to get.

  `GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/process/processes?api-version=7.1-preview.1`
- Work item type: It is `ProcessName.WorkItemType`. For example, the name of my inherited process is `ag`, and my work item type is Epic, then its value is `ag.Epic`.
- defaultValue: The default value of TargetDate. The time zone it corresponds to is UTC. So you need to convert it according to your actual time zone. For example, for the time zone UTC+2, time should be set to 21:59:00.000Z. If you are not sure what your time should be set to, you can manually set the time of a work item to 11:59PM, and then run REST API [Work Items - Get Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/get-work-item?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP) to check the value of `Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.TargetDate`.

  `GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?api-version=7.1-preview.3`

Then, when you try to create a new work item, for example, an Epic, the default value of time is 11:59PM. You can change the date according to your actual needs.
[image]